# Application server: Tomcat, Glassfish, Jetty

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish

In the context of a project we have to write a client/server application in Java. For this purpose we designed the server and the client application using HTTP requests/responses and a database. As we are fresh to this kind of project I have looked for a http server that could handle the basic tasks (such as http parser, db interaction, making/receiving HTTP response/request..). I found that server like Tomcat, Jetty and glassfish may answer to these questions (Or I did not correctly understood), but I am puzzled by some points:

- How these application server work?
- How can I write my service and then embed it in the application server? (API's, tutorials, good documentation, courses,...)
- Which one is best suited for this kind of project?
- Is there other simpler solutions?
- Am I wrong?

There is no web page to display, only use HTTP as simple communication protocol that will contain data (iCalendar format) and will perform insert/get/modify/delete operations on the database after some controls.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: @AlexBolobuteIs it clear for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand you serach something and want some useful links to start, lets try to answer your question:

> How these application server work?

- Basically when they are run it starts to listen a port(it can be change or configurable according to server you select tomcat default 8080 etc.) and when a new request made by clients to this port server hadle it and return the answer according to your code logic.

> How can I write my service and then embed it in the application server? (API's, tutorials, good documentation, courses,...)

- Actually if you didn't need any web page it means you just need an API, but you should learn how to write an servlet in Java Web Projects. So don't check web page technologies just check Servlet Programming, this are some useful links; [link1](http://www.journaldev.com/1854/java-web-application-tutorial-for-beginners), [link2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html)

> Which one is best suited for this kind of project?

- You should be simple as possible, but i can offer Tomcat, large community support (a lot of stackoverflow question already answered)

> Is there other simpler solutions?

- You can search more lightweight servers like [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty/)(embedded server)

> Am I wrong?

- No :)

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answer! Actually I've looked for API's but as we are running out of time I'was looking for something secure, fast and easy. Your link answer well to my questions. I think I will look for Jetty or Tomcat and make some tests :)